# How to access item index in MVC list view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm creating a view where the model is List of Foo.  I want to create a list with an actionlink to select a given Foo item and need to pass it back to the controller. However, there is nothing unique enough in Foo to tie to the actionlink. I'd like to pass the index of the item in Foo but don't know how to get the index from the model inside of the view.

Is this possible to do this without creating a viewmodel that contains the index?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post the code you have for your View, and you'll likely get more assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean `@for(int i=0; i<Model.Count; i++)`, then use i as the id? But you'll need to make sure the positions won't change.

I think it will be better to have ids on Foo in the long term.

Comment: +1 that's a good approach given the requirements. And I also agree that the desired approach could be prone to bugs... Index is likely to change.

Comment: How would I access properties of the model ? @Model[i].PropertyName doesn't work.

Comment: @Charlino - The model is held in session so the index won't change.

Comment: @BillMartin How does `@Model[i].PropertyName` not work? If you are using a `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`, it should work.

Comment: @Charlino That was it. The model was an IEnumerable rather than an IList. IEnumerable doesn't support indexing. Thanks!!